# for loop not working on object

Tags: javascript, oop

So my function is insanely simple right now...

```
setUpButtons: function(items) {
    console.log(typeof items); //Logs Object
    console.log(items); //Logs ["<li class="0">Click Me</li>", "<li class="1">Click Me Too</li>"]
        for(var index in items) {
            console.log(items[index]); //does not log
            console.log("HELLO"); //does not log
        }
}
```

I can't see a reason why I can't loop through that. I have tried $(items).each(function() as well and nothing will output. Any ideas? Here is how that items object gets built...

```
setButtons: function(type) {
    var that = this;
    var items = [];
    $.getJSON("button_list.php?type=" + type, function(data) {
        $.each(data.buttons, function(key, val) {
            console.log(items);
            items.push("<li class='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>");
        });
        console.log(items);
    });
    that.buttons = items;
},
```

Comment: Whatever the problem is, you shouldn't be using `for .. in` on an `Array`. Use `for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++ i)` instead.

Comment: have you tried using a normal for: `for(var index = 0, len = items.length; index < len; index++) {`; for-in should not be used to iterate over Array elements.

Comment: code edited above to show origin of items object. @Dan D yep tried everything I could think of to iterate through it, found out that if I console.log(items.length) it logs 0. not sure how that is possible at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `for in` on an array which doesn't have properties to be assigned to `index` as if you were iterating over an object literal.

Replace with this:

```
for(var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++){ 
    console.log(items[i]);
    console.log('HELLO');
}
```

Comment: Did that, it doesn't work either... when i console.log(typeof items) it outputs an object, when I console.log(items) it show the ["<li..."] When I console.log(items.length); it outputs 0

Comment: Do `items = [].slice.call(items);` and see what happens. It should coerce it into an array and therefore be able to work in this `for` loop.

Comment: how can items.length be 0? that doesn't make any sense at all

Comment: Are you sure? It shouldn't. I just tried on jsFiddle and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/CVXFq/

Comment: yep, and when I console.log(items.length) it logs 0 it really makes no sense at all. How can there be an object in items, but it's length be 0

Comment: `typeof []` will return 'object', but it's not an object literal. This is a fundamental JavaScript hiccup.

Answer (score 0):

I would think you want a "Foreach" with the syntax you are showing... options would be either

```
foreach (var x in items) {
  // do something with items[x]
}
```

or

```
for (var x = 0; x<items; x++) {
  // do something with items[x]
}
```

I don't think you can combine the two

Comment: Actually, in ES5 you would do `items.forEach(function(item) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @EricWendelin you can try using forEach:

```
var d = { 
setUpButtons: function(items) {
    console.log(typeof items); //Logs Object
    console.log(items); //Logs ["<li class="0">Click Me</li>", "<li class="1">Click Me Too</li>"]
    items.forEach(function(t) {
        console.log(t); 
    })
}  }
d.setUpButtons(['<li class="0">Click Me</li>', '<li class="1">Click Me Too</li>']);
```